# React Native [React Native Elements] Search Bar CancelButtonText

Tags: react-native

React-Native
- IOS
- React-Native (0.53.0)
- React-Native-Elements ("^.19.0")

I am having trouble displaying the 'Cancel' button next to my React-Native-Element Search Bar when user selects search bar.   Image provided of what I am trying to achieve

[image: Unable to see the 'CANCEL' text at any time]

Here is my code snippet :

```
    <SearchBar
         lightTheme round
         placeholder="Test"
         onSubmitEditing={()=>{this.doSomething()}}
         cancelButtonText = "Cancel"
     />
```

[image]

Reference for React-Native-Element Search Bar
https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html

Comment: It is possible that it is looking for a platform. Try plugging in platform=“ios” just to see what happens. If that doesn’t work, I would try looking at some of the issues that are on the package to see if it has already been answered

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I tried what you asked and it didn't change anything.  Also check the issues and was not able to find a related issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**`docs`**](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/versions.html) are different for the **latest stable release** and the **beta release**.

If you have **beta releese**, you may add [**`cancelButtonTitle`**](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html#cancelbuttontitle) prop to your [SearchBar](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html)

```
<SearchBar
  showLoading
  platform="ios"
  cancelButtonTitle="Cancel"
  placeholder='Search' />
```

Comment: Your right for pointing this out. I am using version Current Stable Version 0.19.0 which does not have a 'cancel' button property. Updates package.json to be version 1.0.0-beta4 and everything worked perfect.  THANKS!